# Chaining belongs_to relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working with a set of models that have straightforward `belongs_to` relationships.  For example D `belongs_to` `C` which `belongs_to` B which `belongs_to` A.  I often find myself needing to get access to "D's A", which I would typically write `d_instance.c.b.a`, but that gets old really quick.

Is there some magic I can add to the model of D which would jump me directly to `d_instance.a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `through` with `belongs_to`, but you can use `delegate`.  Here is the documentation for `delegate`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

You can use `delegate` on a model to call a method from another class as if it belonged to the model. In these example, uppercase is the class and lowercase is either an instance of the class or a method name. So in your case `D` has a method `#c` such that `d.c` returns the associated instance of `C`. `C` has a method `#b` such that `c.b` returns the associated instance of `B`, and `B` has a method `#a` that returns the associated instance of `A`.

If you go to the `D` model and `delegate` `#b` to `C`, when you call `d.b` it will be the same as if you called `d.c.b`. As this is probably confusing, here is the code you need:

```
class D < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :this, :that, :the_other

  belongs_to :c

  delegate :b, to: :c
  delegate :a, to: :b

end
```

Once you have restarted your server `d.a` will give you the same result as `d.c.b.a`

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to try this one out first.

Comment: @Joe, I made one typo in `delegate`, I just fixed it.

Comment: @Zajn, thanks for your response as well.  This answer is preferred, though, as it provides the flexibility to address any of the parent objects directly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a method for instances `D` that returns the proper association:

```
class D
...
  def a
    self.c.b.a
  end
end
```